# Sending 120 mails by Javamail using Gmail account, but got exception after 80/90 mails

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

Got the below exception while send mails in a loop of 120. First 80/85 mails are success but the remaining got exceptions.

javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1564)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1551)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1489)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1054)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:634)

Below is my code for sending mails. From, To, Subject, Body etc. are same for all 120 mails.

```
    try {
        Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");
        tr.connect(this.SMTPServer, this.UserName, this.Password);
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to the mail server.");
        tr.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: my guess is they gmail does not allow you to use their mail server for mass-mailing.

Comment: Your SMTP server refused to accept any further connections from you. You can contact the owner of the server to find out why, but they likely think you're being abusive. If you're sending out mass mailings, find (and pay for) your own provider.