# how to solve Exception(java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host) while sending smtp mails in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, email, smtp, bulk

I am using an SMTP server to send bulk e-mails (approximately 500 to 1000) in Java. To speed up the process, I am calling:

`transport.sendMessage(msg,  msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO))`

to connect once per thread. The first 60 to 80 emails are being sent without a problem, but there are exceptions being thrown for the remaining emails:

```
\>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>RSET
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (MAIL) q20sm22831112pfi.5 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2203)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1694)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1194)
at Service.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:668)
at Service.EmailService.run(EmailService.java:558)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
inside sending mail 
The time is 17:7:16
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<choudhary.winni@gmail.com>
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2260)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2247)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2177)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1694)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1194)
```

Comment: You need to know why the SMTP server disconnected you.  Most likely because you were sending too many emails. I suggest you read the server logs or contact your service provider.

Comment: yes i am sending too many emails.is there any limit for smtp sever to send mails?

Comment: There doesn't have to be but most server would have a limit to prevent spam and overloading the server. I suggest you ask them what the limit is.

Comment: i dont have any serice provider i am using simple gmail for this

Comment: In that case, you need to ask the provider of gmail, i.e. google.  Most likely you can google to find out this limit because someone has probably hit this limit before.

Comment: please refer , [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135927/sending-120-mails-by-javamail-using-gmail-account-but-got-exception-after-80-90)  and [google link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en). Its most likely email limit thing.